# How can I switch a flag for multiple records at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using `Mailboxer` gem.

The rows are checked, and the view is passing plural IDs, but this action only trashes 1st ID#'s record when it receives parameters.

What do I need to do to trash all records corresponding to the ID's passed in the parameters?

Parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"35UoVt+dvwrGAgg+KZjn8jCZjlkdPj1ktCg5ASyCI4w=",
 "checked_items"=>{"15"=>"15",
 "14"=>"14"},
 "commit"=>"Trash All Checked"}
```

Action

```
def discard

  conversation = Conversation.find_by_id(params[:checked_items].keys)

  if conversation

    current_user.trash(conversation)

    flash[:notice] = "Message sent to trash."

  else

    conversations = Conversation.find(params[:conversations])

    conversations.each { |c| current_user.trash(c) }

    flash[:notice] = "Messages sent to trash."

  end

  redirect_to :back

end
```

Comment: Instead of find_by_id use find_all_by_id and you will get all conversations then trash one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of find_by_id use find_all_by_id and you will get all conversations then trash one by one.